# Error when running API call in R using comprador() package

Tags: api, ssl, curl, error-handling

I get this error when I try to run an API call using ct_search() from comtradr() package in R .

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
      SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given enough details, but it could be related to this:
https://support.sectigo.com/articles/Knowledge/Sectigo-AddTrust-External-CA-Root-Expiring-May-30-2020

If you are on a Linux machine that you are running curl from, you can do the following:

```
$ sudo vi /etc/ca-certificates.conf
add an exclamation point in front of the line that says "mozilla/AddTrust_External_Root.crt" and save the file
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install ca-certificates
$ sudo update-ca-certificates -f -v
```